# Is power series where coefficeint come from Q countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that P[x] with coefficient from Q is countable, since it can be represented as n-tuple and hence all such n-tuple is the countable union (the component) of finite (the value of n) set and hence is countable. Can I extend this logic to power series where n tend to infinity? (I think yes because this would be then countable union of countable)

Answer (score 2):

No. Given a binary expansion $0.a_1a_2\dots$ you can create a convergent power series by $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{2^k}$$

These series are all different, and there are uncountably many of them because there are uncountably many reals in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

To see this notice that the coefficients of a power series $(a_0,a_1,\ldots)$ express any infinite sequence of numbers. Thus we can do the cantor diagonalization argument to prove that the set of all power series is uncontable i.e. the same argument used to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

The reason why you can not use the reasoning of "A countable union of countable sets is countable" is that a powerseries can not be expressed that way. Rather If you take the union of all polynomials, you will not get a powerseries, just all polynomials (which are all finite).

Answer (score 1):

No.

The countability of $\mathbb Q[x]$ rests on the countability of $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Q^n$$ wich is a countable union of countable sets.

Looking at polynomials $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ with e.g. $a_n\in\{0,1]$ realize that each of them corresponds with an element of $[0,1]$ in the sense that  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\mapsto0.a_0a_1\cdots$ in binary notation.

Set $[0,1]$ is not countable.